# tput returns always 80 in a capturing output subshell *and* in a script (Cygwin/Bash)

Tags: bash, cygwin, ncurses

I'm experiencing something kinda weird. In a interactive Cygwin console, here's what I get if I play with tput:

```
$ tput cols
210
$ (tput cols)
210
$ echo $(tput cols)
210
```

So all is ok. However, If I run those commands in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
tput cols
(tput cols)
echo $(tput cols)
```

I get:

```
210
210
80
```

It happens on a given installation  (W2012 Server 64 - mintty `2.6.1` - bash `4.3.46(7)-release`), but not in another (W2008 Server 32 - mintty `2.8.4` - bash `4.4.12(3)-release`).

Comment: Have you had the occasion to test this on a fresh install of  `mintty 2.6.1` ? I've tried on my computer running WSL, and I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: @Aserre, not yet the occasion (professional stuff, performing a fresh install will prevent me to work on my duty :)). Also I added bash versions.

Comment: What do `echo "$COLUMNS"` and `shopt checkwinsize` output when added to your script? Does adding `shopt -s checkwinsize` to the beginning of your script help?

Comment: Cross-referencing with https://superuser.com/questions/1135171/stderr-redirection-in-subshell-changes-output-of-tput (which appears to be a slightly-different issue, but one which some readers may find helpful, as the title of this question is more or less a match).

Comment: @phils, thanks, this answers sounds quite interesting and might be a part of the answer.